# How do I make my interface (or OS) output stereo with a mono mic that outputs on the left channel?

Tags: microphone, sound, audio-interfaces, voice-over

I have a Scarlett Solo interface and I'm using a Shure SM57 mic, plugged in the interface mic input with an XLR m-f cable. The interface is connected via USB to my PC.

When I record in a DAW like Pro Tools First or Ableton Live 9 (lite), I can get a stereo sound. But outside of a DAW, the mic output is always on the left channel only.

However, I need to use the mic for conferencing or live voice-overs too and I don't have any way to make the output from the mic go on both left and right channels.

Is there any software that I could install at system level to force stereo output from a mono mic or what other method I could use to get that while using the mic for voice-over stuff?

I've searched for an answer both here and on the internet, but I can't find a proper answer. The Focusrite site only refers to this in the context of using a DAW. Couldn't see an answer in the search results here either (or maybe I missed it). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Oh well, nevermind, I solved this issue. Actually a friend told me. I will write the answer here so if anyone else needs it they can find it.

It's a simple setting. If you are using Windows 10, just go to the sound devices, go to the **Recording** tab and select the **Default Format** for recording as: **1 channel** (and whichever bit depth and sample rate you want). If you select 2 channels and you are only using one channel with mono input, the system will expect audio from two separate channels, so it will keep the microphone on the left. Once you select 1 channel it will place that channel in the centre.